# Python script won't let me exit after executing a exe in os.system

Tags: python-2.7, os.system

```
def x():
    os.system('x.exe')
    sys.exit()
```

This is what i used in my script but when i run the program it never gets up to sys.exit.

Comment: Does your script hang? The call to `os.system('x.exe')` will wait for 'x.exe' to finish running before continuing with the script.

Comment: subprocess.Popen() worked best because the script used to hang now it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think os.system function will execute shell command. and sys.exit() command is no problem . I suggest you to make a test ,like the following script:

import sys

sys.exit()

print "sys.exit is not Ok!"

Comment: it was not sys.exit() it was actually the os.system() command os.system i found is a blocking call and subprocess.Popen is not.